# Error al implementar comparable en lista generica

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy intentando comparar los valores dentro de mis nodos con la interfaz `Comparable`. Pero a la hora de implementar el metodo `compareTo` me da error: Dice que el operador no puede ser aplicado a `<E>` (que es mi valor generico).

Os dejo codigo:

```
public class LEGultimoEC<E> extends LEGultimo<E> implements Comparable<NodoLEG<E>> {

    public LEGultimoEC(NodoLEG<E> primero, NodoLEG<E> ultimo) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(NodoLEG<E> o) {
        int resultado = 0;
        if(o.getDato()<o.getSiguiente().getDato()){
            return -1;
        }else if(o.getDato()>o.getSiguiente().getDato()){
            return  1;
        }
    }
}
```

El valor que hay en dato es `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El parámetro de tipo `E` no tiene ninguna restricción en tu clase `LEGultimoEC<E>` por lo que puede ser cualquier clase, incluso simplemente `Object`.

El operador `<` y `>` solo puede ser ocupado en los tipos primitivos numéricos (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`, `float`, `double`) o en aquellos tipos que pueden ser convertidos via *unboxing* a esos tipos.

Por lo tanto nunca va a ser valido comparar:

```
E e1 = ...
E e2 = ...
if(e1 < e2) {...}
```

Para que eso sea posible tendrías que establecer algún límite superior (en inglés *upper bound*) a ese tipo paramétrico que te permita usar el operador, de la siguiente forma:

```
class LEGultimoEC<E extends Integer>
```

Con eso, ya podrías utilizar el operador y podrías escribir `LEGultimoEC<Integer>`. Pero no te serviría de mucho ya que solo podrías parametrizar con `Integer` y nada más (`Integer` es final).

---

La forma mas útil, es la que te sugiere [@dmmiralles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151807/73136), en lugar de restringir a alguna clase en la que puedas usar el operador, restringe a `Comparable`:

```
class LEGultimoEC<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

Con eso, en lugar de usar el operador, usas:

```
E e1 = ...
E e2 = ...
if(e1.compareTo(e2) < 0) {...}
```

La definición de tu clase entonces quedaría un tanto más extensa:

```
public class LEGultimoEC<E extends Comparable<E>>
    extends LEGultimo<E> implements Comparable<NodoLEG<E>> {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para esto debes tener en cuenta 2 cosas:

1. En tiempo de compilacion no se sabe que E es un entero, por tanto no se puede aplicar el operador '<' para comparar, para eso debes usar el metodo compareTo de Comparable.
2. Para poder complimentar el punto 1, debes asegurarte que el generico E hereda de Comparable (Genericidad Restringida).

Comment: Ya esta heredando estoy implementandole la interfaz comparable.